# asp.net webforms access nested properties from .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, custom-controls

I want to be able to access properties in .aspx pages the same way I can access the CssClass property of the ItemStyle property belonging to a BoundField.

```
<asp:BoundColumn ItemStyle-CssClass="foo" />
```

In order to do this I have something like this:

```
public class ItemProperties
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    // ...
}

class MyCustomControl
{
    // ...
    public ItemProperties ItemProperties { get; }

    // ...
}
```

and I tried to use it like this in a .aspx page:

```
<myTag:MyCustomControl runat="server" ItemProperties-Prop1="test" />
```

The only propbem is that unlike a boundField I get the error:

> Parser Error Message: Type 'MyNamespace.MyCustomControl' does not have
>   a public property named 'ItemProperties-Prop1'.

I have tried to set some of the annotations of the ItemStyle class from asp.net and to use Component as the base class, I also tried the sintax ItemProperties.Prop1 instead of ItemProperties-Prop1 but nothing seems to help. Any ideas?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, is what you are trying to do define a collection of 1-n sub-properties (ideally with a predictable naming scheme) on a user control where the number is not known until run-time?

Comment: @JimMSDN: No, I just want to be able to reference a property of a property in aspx. In code it would look like this: obj1.Prop1.Prop2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is this:

```
<myTag:MyCustomControl runat="server">
   <ItemProperties Prop1="test" />
</myTag:MyCustomControl>
```

The property can be decorated with `[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]`. However this is the default behavior, so I think you can simply don't do it.

I forgot to say that you also need to mark the properties of `ItemProperties` class with `[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.Attribute)]`. If you don't, the syntax would be:

```
<myTag:MyCustomControl runat="server">
   <ItemProperties>
     <Prop1>test</Prop1>
   </ItemProperties>
</myTag:MyCustomControl>
```

Comment: for me it also works without the [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.Attribute)] annotation. So I don't know if that is mandatory. Also I just noticed that the alternative syntax: <myTag:MyCustomControl runat="server" ItemProperties-Prop1="test" /> also worked... I just misspelled my property name...